# Need advice with switch

Tags: c#

I have two fields. One is time picker where i saving time of shifts and second is combobox where I have enum of shifts.

Shifts type is firstShift = morning, secondShift = afternoon, thirdShift = midnight.  All shifts have startTime and endTime.

Then in switch i write value if its between time interval.

When I choose afternoon shift from combobox, then in timepicker is set time for afternoon shift, which is correct.

The problem is when i choose morning shift, which is before afternoon. If I choose morning shift , time set correct, but switch call second time and set midnight shift. Morning shift is from 06:00AM - 14:00PM and Midnight is from 10:00PM - 06:00 AM.

This is the code which I'm using for write time by selected shift type.

```
ListOfShifts = new ObservableCollection<EShifts>()
{
    new EShifts { 
        StartTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 06, 00, 00), 
        EndTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 14, 00, 00), 
        ShiftDesc = StringEnum<Shifts>.ToString(Shifts.PrvniSmena), 
        ShiftType = Shifts.PrvniSmena
    },
    new EShifts { 
        StartTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 14, 00, 00), 
        EndTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 22, 00, 00), 
        ShiftDesc = StringEnum<Shifts>.ToString(Shifts.DruhaSmena), 
        ShiftType = Shifts.DruhaSmena
    },
    new EShifts { 
        StartTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 22, 00, 00), 
        EndTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 06, 00, 00).AddDays(1), 
        ShiftDesc = StringEnum<Shifts>.ToString(Shifts.TretiSmena), 
        ShiftType = Shifts.TretiSmena
    }
};
```

There is a code which im using for write time by selected shift type

```
DateTime lastTime = Convert.ToDateTime(HourOfLoading);

if (HourOfLoading == null)
{
    lastTime = DateTime.Now;
}

if (selectedShift != null)
{
    // vyplnění času nakládky podle směn
    switch (selectedShift.ShiftType)
    {
        case Shifts.PrvniSmena:
            if (!(lastTime >= selectedShift.StartTime && lastTime < selectedShift.EndTime))
                HourOfLoading = selectedShift.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm");
            break;
        case Shifts.DruhaSmena:
            if (!(lastTime >= selectedShift.StartTime && lastTime < selectedShift.EndTime))
                HourOfLoading = selectedShift.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm");
            break;
        case Shifts.TretiSmena:
            if (!(lastTime >= selectedShift.StartTime && lastTime < selectedShift.EndTime))
                HourOfLoading = selectedShift.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm");
            break;
    }
}
```

The result what I need is when i set in combobox back to morning shift, then show time which will start at 06:00.

Comment: When you say that your "switch call second time", do you mean that the method containing that switch gets invoked again? If so, could you debug to find what exactly invokes it? Some event on your time picker or your combobox perhaps?

Comment: I suggest you add a breakpoint in your `switch` statement to see a) what value `selectedShift.ShiftType` is, and b) to look at the call stack and see where it's being called from - you've given two unrelated pieces of code in your question, and no indication of how they're connected.

Comment: I'd guess this is a UI design problem.  You're entering times based on a 12 hour clock instead of a 24 hour clock.  So you'll also need am/pm radiobuttons to know whether it is a time in the morning or afternoon/night.